# Print multiple pages

Tags: vb.net

I'm converting from VB5 and am trying to get the equivalent of printer.NewPage in VB.NET.
My code is given below, but it simply prints the two lines on a single page.
The program prints two pages of calculated results (arrays etc), it is not reading and printing a file.
How do I get a second page?

```
Private Sub PrintGeneralReport()

    Dim PrintPreviewSelected As Boolean = True

    'Set the doc to print
    Dim pDoc As New PrintDocument
    pDoc.PrintController = New StandardPrintController   'turns off the printing page x of y dialog

    'Get the printer to use
    If Me.PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        pDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = Me.PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
        'pDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Margins(75, 50, 50, 50)
        pDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Margins(40, 10, 10, 10)
        pDoc.OriginAtMargins = True

    Else
        pDoc = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Install the PrintPage event handler.
    AddHandler pDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintGenReport

    If PrintPreviewSelected Then
        ''print preview
        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = pDoc
        PrintPreviewDialog1.UseAntiAlias = True
        PrintPreviewDialog1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Else

        'just print
        pDoc.Print()
    End If

    RemoveHandler pDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintGenReport

End Sub

Private Sub PrintGenReport(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)

    Dim fnt10 As Font = New Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Page 1", fnt10, Brushes.Black, 20, 100)
    'ROARK1.Print_GeneralReportRK(Me, e)
    e.HasMorePages = True
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Page 2", fnt10, Brushes.Black, 20, 200)
    'ROARK1.Print_MemberActions(e)
    e.HasMorePages = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Add a PageNumber variable to your class.  Initialize it to 0 in the BeginPrint event and increment it in the PrintPage event.  Now you can use a Select statement to figure out what to print.

Comment: @HansPassant. Thanks. What I hadn't appreciated was that the .hasmorepages action calls the printpage again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private PageNum As Integer = 1

Private Sub PrintGenReport(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    Dim fnt10 As Font = New Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Page " & PageNum.ToString(), fnt10, Brushes.Black, 20, 100 * PageNum)

    e.HasMorePages = (PageNum < 2)
    PageNum += 1
End Sub
```

Note the `PageNum` variable is defined at the class level. You should also add a line to the `PrintGeneralReport()` method to set it back to `1` at the beginning of each print job.

Comment: This question is very old, but it came up in a search for a question to use as a reference/duplicate, and I thought it could use an answer.